# how to use umbraco rich textbox in custom property editor

Tags: umbraco

I am new to umbraco. I am trying to create a new custom property editor in the new umbraco 7. But I am stuck at trying to add a umbraco rich textbox (tinyMCE) in my edit page.
Can someone tell me how to do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

go edit your document type in the settings tree.
select the "generic properties" tab and add a field of text with the type "richtext editor"